# Angular ng-change or ng-click for select can't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-change

It's a sample about ng-change with checkbox.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m32jxS6rcfySx1739c56?p=preview)

I'd like to make the checkbox into a selection but failed.
Here's the code:

```
<select>
  <option ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()">1</option>
  <option ng-model="confirmed" ng-click="change()">2</option>
</select>
```

If somebody could help I'll be appreciate.

Comment: those should be given to select element not option

Comment: @ArunPJohny If every option do the different functions?

Comment: in that case you can use a `if...else/switch` condition in the change handler to call other methods...

Comment: You should bind the change event to the select box instead doing it for options. Somehting like - <select ng-change ="function_to_be_called()"> and in the function you can take the value of the option and invoke different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

controller:

```
$scope.selectChange = function() {
    switch($scope.confirmed) {
      case '1': $scope.selected = '1';break;

      case '2': $scope.selected = '2';break;
    }
  }
```

html:

```
<select ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="selectChange()">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>

<p>{{selected}}</p>
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/N85UYTeHwRInfp60ZLsJ?p=preview

Comment: It's clear. I just combine it with ng-options. Thanks, that helps me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind them to the select element not option

```
<select ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put ng-click in select not in option

```
 <div class="input-group">
      <select class="form-control" placeholder="Type template" ng-model="eventID" ng-click="viewRuleByEvent(eventID)">
         <option value="" selected>Select Event</option>
         <option selected value="all">All Event</option>
         <option ng-repeat="event in events" value="{{event.id}}">{{event.name}}</option>
      </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
<select ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```